# iPhone/iPad Enable only horizontal&Vertical swipes in a CoverFlow in TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, gesture, swipe, coverflow

I have a table view and each cell of it contains a coverFlow (implemented using OpenFlow Lib).

When I swipe(or scroll) left to right to select an item in the coverflow, I have to be very careful, because if I swipe not so horizontally, it will result in the tableView being scrolled(slightly up or down) and the coverFlow delegate won't react to the change of selection.

**So I want the view only to detect left and right swipe gesture which will result in changing selection of coverFlow, and Up and Down swipe which will make the table to scroll down!**[Here is a basic concept of the view I just mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHgVD.png)

Any Ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should check this doc :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Create homemade event handlers and implement the canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer and canPreventGestureRecognizer methods.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the respond! so I should add a gestureRecognizer to my Cell's view and prevent up and down gestures? is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't think gestureRecognizer could help, since the OpenFlow was implemented by overriding touch begin/move/end. My feeling is that I should customize those methods of a tableview..